# Is there a way for a UIViewController to know when it becomes a "topmost" view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

The app I'm working on has a main view controller, which is presenting different view controllers modally. These view controllers may present their own child view controllers modally.

At random times the main view controller may receive a notification to present a message (via message view controller) to the user, but the message view controller should not be presented until all other currently presented view controllers are dismissed.

Is there a reliable way for the main view controller to figure out when the modally presented view controller and its children are dismissed?

I've tried overriding the `dismiss(animated:completion:)` in the main view controller, but it is not called if the modally presented view controller calls `self.dismiss(animated:completion:)`. I've also tried with overriding `viewDidAppear(_:)` in the main view controller, but it is not called if the modally presented view controller is presented with presentation style `.overFullScreen`.

Any ideas?

Edit: I'm not asking how to figure out if the main view controller is topmost, I'm asking how can the view controller know **when** it becomes the topmost view controller.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top most UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Do you use Unwind Segue?

Comment: @ppm I'm not using unwind segue. Those modally presented view controllers are other people code and I may not be able to affect how they present their child view controllers nor how they dismiss themselves.

Comment: @MichaelFourre Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Honey Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question. I've added a clarification to the question.

Comment: @SrđanStanić I didn't mean as a duplicate. I meant it can be helpful

Comment: @Honey Ok, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: @SrđanStanić That may be hard ;-) Is there any way to know those view controllers presented from main view controller (immediate child of mainVC) are dismissed? like delegate, etc. You may be assume it as all VCs are dismissed.

Comment: Add a BOOL property, and make it YES when the modals are presented. and on viewDidAppear on your "main" viewController, just check against the bool and you will know if the view appeared from a "popped subviews" or not.

Comment: @ppm that is precisely my question :) I'm trying to figure out when the immediate children are dismissed, because their children either already are dismissed or will be dismissed at that moment. What is puzzling for me here is this part of the Appl docs: _"To dismiss a presented view controller, call the dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: method of the presenting view controller. You can also call this method on the presented view controller itself. When you call the method on the presented view controller, UIKit automatically forwards the request to the presenting view controller."_

Comment: @ppm But when dismiss() is called on the presented view controller, dismiss() on the presenting view controller does not get executed as far as I can see.

Comment: @Sneak I'm not sure I'm following. The question already addresses the viewDidAppear() approach. Unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: @SrđanStanić I am not familiar with overFullScreen . The easiest solution and to avoid wierd notifications cent across the app, is just create a delegate on the first presented view controller. And when you present it , set its delegate to the mainViewController, and call the delegate when you pop the presented view. If you have multiple views, you can check in the navigationController if all the attached viewControllers are popped you can call the delegate. Maybe this is the solution for you?

Comment: @Sneak Those modally presented view controllers are other people's code and I am not able to modify them. Or at least I'm looking for a solution that does not require modifying their code. Also there is no navigation controller in this setup.

Comment: @SrđanStanić http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271880/viewdidappear-not-called-when-the-modal-view-is-dismissed