# ViewDidAppear not called automatically

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsviewcontroller

I have a `HomeViewController` that is opening a `WelcomeViewController` using segue and is from type Sheet.

In `WelcomeViewController` the User is entering information and then closing(dismissing) it. After `WelcomeViewController` is closed I want to update `HomeViewController` by changing the `String` value of a `TextField`.

The Problem is, that `ViewDidAppear` in `HomeViewController` is not called after dismissing `WelcomeViewController`. I did not have this Problem before when developing for iOS.

How can I fix this? I tried to call it manually but got problems, because my `IBOutlets` were set to nil and I could not change the text in my `TextField`.

This is the code that invokes the segue:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcome", sender: self)
```

this is my `viewDidAppear` in `HomeViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
   super.viewDidAppear()
   if (CoreDataAccess().countUsers() == 0) {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcome", sender: self)
   } else {
       //continue execution..
   }
}
```

In `WelcomeViewController` I dismiss the `ViewController` using this code

```
dismiss(self)
```

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271880/viewdidappear-not-called-when-the-modal-view-is-dismissed

Comment: Post the code that creates your view controller/invokes the segue, and also post your viewDidAppear method. (you should never call that method. That's what hte system does.)

Comment: @DuncanC I posted the code

Comment: Use a delegate. viewDidAppear will not be called in your case

Comment: Are you doing anything in `prepare(for segue:)`? Maybe passing the instance of `HomeViewController`? Also, I've never used a "Sheet" type segue but why to create an unwind segue?

Comment: Your outlets should not be nil. how are you trying to pass the data from welcomeViewController back to first screen?you need to show more code. your problem is not clear

Comment: @dfd no, I don't have a prepare(for segue:)

Comment: @Scriptable I am using CoreData to save the data. And then display it in homeViewController

Comment: @Scriptable I created the segue in my Storyboard and calling it with the identifier "welcome" manually from code... Other code is only saving and loading from CoreData and is not related to my Problem.

Comment: I waited for others more experienced than me, and nothing. So. From my perspective? You haven't given us enough to help. My questions? Ok... you didn't see a need for `prepare(for: segue:)`... why? That **a** standard way for pass the *source* view controller to it's *target*. You never answered @ullstrm... why not try using a delegate? It works *very* well when *presenting* another view controller form one. Finally, did @Kevinosaurio help? Or at least give you the correct direction? This is now on **you** to provide something more....

Comment: I just found the solution using a delegate. As @ullstrm said, in my case viewDidAppear will not be called. Using the delegate my textfields were not set to nil anymore. Will post the solution now.. I did not see the need for prepare, because I don't pass any data to my second ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it using a `delegate`.
Thanks to @ullstrm for the suggestion.

First I added this protocol to `HomeViewController`

```
protocol WelcomeDelegate {
    func insertData(_ name: String, birthday: Date)
}
```

Then this `prepare(for segue:)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationController as? WelcomeViewController {
        destinationViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

And this extension at the bottom (I know it's not ok to call viewDidAppear manually , but it's working for now)

```
extension HomeViewController : WelcomeDelegate {
    func insertData(_ name: String, birthday: Date) {
        viewDidAppear()
    }
}
```

Then in `WelcomeViewController` I added this variable

```
var delegate:WelcomeDelegate? = nil
```

And this line right before `dismiss(self)`

```
self.delegate?.insertData(tfName.stringValue, birthday: dpAge.dateValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code to ViewWillAppear() instead of ViewDidAppear().

or you call a method in the HomeViewController when dismissing WelcomeViewcontroller

```
dismiss(animated: true) {
   self.presentedViewController.myMethod()
}
```

Comment: Not working, ViewWillAppear() is also not called after i dismiss my second ViewController.

Comment: call a method in the HomeViewController when dismissing WelcomeViewcontroller

dismiss(animated: true) {
   self.presentedViewController.myMethod()
}

let me know..

Comment: Yes, I can call a method, but this does not help me get access to my TextField. Without calling ViewDidAppear my IBOutlets are set to nil.